vba word. Find phrase in range
I want to check Document's range and check if phrase "form     CAPTION" exists but not "subform     CAPTION". I thought that .MatchWholeWord = True is the key to do it, but the following code returns .Found = TRUE always
Sub CheckIfForm()
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim searchRange As Range
    Dim searchText As String
    
    ' Set the search text
    searchText = "form" & String(25, " ") & "CAPTION"
    
    ' Set the document and search range
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Set searchRange = doc.Range
    
    ' Find the search text
    With searchRange.Find
        .Text = searchText
        .MatchWholeWord = True ' Match only whole words
        .MatchCase = False ' Case insensitive
        .Wrap = wdFindStop ' Stop at the end of the document
        .Execute
        
        ' Check if the text is found
        If .Found Then
            MsgBox "The phrase """ & searchText & """ was found.", vbInformation
        Else
            MsgBox "The phrase """ & searchText & """ was not found.", vbExclamation
        End If
    End With
End Sub



Use MatchWildcards option on Find method

Sub WordHighlightReplacement()
    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content
    myRange.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
    Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
    With myRange.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "<form CAPTION>"  ' **
        .MatchWildcards = True  ' **
        .Replacement.Text = "^&"
        .Replacement.Highlight = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub


